# Rewriting my BASE URL - Vbulletin

Tags: url, base-url

I currently have a vbulletin forums that I coppied the theme of to another site to make an application.

with this at the top of the files:

```
<base href="http://example.com/forums/"/><!--[if IE]></base><![endif]-->
```

So I simply copied/pasted the source code then modified the body.

The problem here is I have a "submit.php" button and what it does it goes based upon the base url so it becomes `http://example.com/forums/submit.php`   but I want it to do this instead:
`http://application.example.com/submit.php`

If I change the BASEURL from the source code the theme won't work anymore and I'm trying to preserve the theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use apache with mod_rewrite, you can create the .htaccess file in the root directory

```
RewriteEngine on

# Don't apply to URLs that go to existing files or folders.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Only apply to URLs that aren't already under folder forums.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forums/

# Rewrite all those to insert /forums.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /forums/$1
```

Documentation
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html